# How to configure diff window in python unittest output?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, diff, test-results

I am testing my application with the inbuilt unittest library (python 3.5) and some of the test cases compare (lists of) dictionaries. When those tests fail the output is not very helpful:

> First differing element 1:
>   {'emi[1557 chars]al': 509201.03, 'remaining_time': None, 'nomin[1213 chars]alse}
>   {'emi[1557 chars]al': '509,201.03', 'remaining_time': None, 'no[1218 chars]alse}

It is easy enough to see which list element is wrong but the limited diff window cuts of the key name of the differing dictionary entry. I know that I can show the full diff with self.maxDiff = None but that's not what I want. I like the limited diff window I just don't like where in the diff it is placed.

Can I configure the placement of the diff window somehow? Alternatively how can I get an informative test failure report with python tests when comparing dictionaries?

Comment: There is no good way to control that behavior, unfortunately.  The code that's doing the shortening is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a31f4cc881992e84d351957bd9ac1a92f882fa39/Lib/unittest/util.py#L24).  You might be able to monkey patch it in there, but I don't recommend doing such things.  Alternatively, you can write your own method or extend the TestCase class to compare the list of dictionaries and have full control over the results.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that somebody thought that was sensible default functionality for the diff. Am I really the first one who finds this not really fit for purpose?

Comment: No, you are not.  This feature was added as part of issue [#18996](https://bugs.python.org/issue18996)--and I can see why... trying to find the difference in a long sequence of characters is definitely not fun.  Someone else complained about the lack of control over the shortening in the issue and issue [#21820](https://bugs.python.org/issue21820) was opened as a result.  Python doesn't have a lot of paid contributors so, if this is something that bugs you, please help them by formulating and contributing a fix.  They're a very welcoming community. :-)

Comment: Ok, thank you John. Can you put your last comment referencing the issues as an answer so I can accept it? I think that given the situation it is the best information and action advice regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was added as part of issue [#18996](https://bugs.python.org/issue18996)--and I can see why... trying to find the difference in a long sequence of characters is definitely not fun. Someone else complained about the lack of control over the shortening in the issue and issue [#21820](https://bugs.python.org/issue21820) was opened as a result.

The code that's doing the shortening is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a31f4cc881992e84d351957bd9ac1a92f882fa39/Lib/unittest/util.py#L24). You might be able to monkey patch it in there, but I don't recommend doing such things. Alternatively, you can write your own method or extend the TestCase class to compare the list of dictionaries and have full control over the results too.